# AddToCart-System: array_push pushes on the "wrong level"?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-push

I'm trying to make an "add to cart" function with this code:

```
if (empty($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array(
        "id" => $_GET['id'],
        "size" => $_POST['size'],
        "count" => $_POST['count']
    );
} else {
    array_push($_SESSION['cart'], array(
        "id" => $_GET['id'],
        "size" => $_POST['size'],
        "count" => $_POST['count']
    ));
}
```

This is the output of `print_r($_SESSION)`:

```
Array
(
    [cart] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [size] => XS
            [count] => 1
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [size] => XS
                    [count] => 1
                )
        )
)
```

You can see in the array what's wrong about my method pushing it. I want the new pushed content on the same "level" as the first entry above, if you know what I mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what do you mean by "*the new pushed content on the same "level" as the first entry above*", following scenario is impossible:

```
$c = array(
           'id' => 1,
           'size' => 'X5',
           'count' => 1,

            // YOU CAN'T HAVE DUPLICATE KEYS IN YOUR ARRAY
           'id' => 2

  );
```

so perhaps you should do array_push in both conditions (for the current example ofcourse), so you would get following structure:

```
$c = array(

          0 => array(
              'id' => 1,
              'size' => 'X5',
              'count' => 1,
           ),

          1 => array(
               'id'=>2,
               'size'=>'X3',
           ...

  );
```

Comment: Yes, your second code example is what I've wanted. Right. Now I just have to figure out to do this.

Comment: Well, replace your if block with just following line then: array_push($_SESSION['cart'], array(
        "id" => $_GET['id'],
        "size" => $_POST['size'],
        "count" => $_POST['count']
    ));

Comment: Thank you. I had it already. Now when I'm adding an item to the cart that was already added (same id) it'll print out "Array" instead of the id, but it array_pushed it. How can I just replace an existing id with the new data entered?

Answer (score 0):

Do this to set your cart instead:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][] = array("id" => $_GET['id'],"size" => $_POST['size'],"count" => $_POST['count']);
```

Then every cart item will be a sub-array of `$_SESSION['cart']`